# Fotorama Covering other Divs - how can I set it to sit behind other content?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fotorama

I am trying to setup a full window Fotorama gallery as the background of my page. I have it working pretty well except it is not sitting behind all of my content (some is in front and some is behind. Can I change the z-index or something to make Fotorama sit at the back?

```
here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/wp58mcpw/5/
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the `z-index`? What was the result? What else have you tried?

Comment: Hey, yes I have with both my content and the Fotorama gallery. The Fotorama css file is quite complex and I'm not really sure which part is controlling the gallery as a whole.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have never used Fotorama, so I can't help you. However, I'd advise you to add a bit more detail to you question, perhaps in the form of a live demo which someone else can fiddle around with in order to attempt to fix the issue.

Comment: Good idea. Here is a jsfiddle link to my code. There is a panel on the left that is sitting behind the gallery. You can see it before the gallery fades in.

http://jsfiddle.net/wp58mcpw/5/

Answer (score 0):

Insert the '.fotorama' div inside an other div (so you do not mess up with his css), now on the outer div insert the css:

```
#fotorama_outer_div_id_here {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```